# Ansible Handlers not working unless I include: them in my play?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have a fresh install of Ansible 2.9.17 and everything works great except handlers :-/
For some reason my ~roles/myservice/handlers/main.yml are not loaded UNLESS I include: the handlers: after every hosts: line in my main.yml files.
example:

```
handlers:
- import_tasks: ../handlers/main.yml
```

I can do this but I find specifying the "same handler" again and again per host: entry annoying. This cant be the best practice of ansible to do it this way.  Anyone else experience this issue before?   There must be a config I'm missing...

## My folder structure :

```
~/roles/myservice/
                 ├── handlers
                 │   └── main.yml
                 ├── tasks
                 └── main.yml
```

## My roles/myservice/handlers/main.yml is:

```
- name: restart myservice
  service:
    name: myservice
    state: restarted
  become: yes
  listen: restart myservice
```

## The roles/myservice/tasks/main.yml is:

```
- name: Installing myservice
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  yum:
    name: myservice.rpm
  notify:
    - restart myservice
```

## But when I run the play:

```
$  ansible-playbook -i hosts roles/myservice/tasks/main.yml --limit myservice
```

PLAY [myservice] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myservice]

TASK [Install myservice.] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myservice]

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [myservice]

TASK [Installing myservice] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ERROR! The requested handler 'restart myservice' was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list

Answer (score 3):

You are executing the `main.yml` file as a playbook, you need to create a playbook that executes the role

```yaml
- name: Playbook
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: all

  roles:
    - myservice
```

Comment: That will work,
  My unedited play had multiple hosts in it so didn't want to do that but it's better to shift it to a role now before I get to deep into my code.  

Thanks Gary!